# how to represent a Binary Search Tree as a database schema?

Tags: database, algorithm

I need to represent Binary Search Tree as a DB schema? How do I do it? Its kind of problem. I dont have any code. I need direction how to show BST as a DB schema.

Comment: On the questions you've asked, click the little check mark next to the answer that was the most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample:

```
id   |    value   |   left_id  |   right_id   |   parent_id (optional)
1    |    100     |     2      |   3          |     NULL    
2    |    50      |   NULL     |   NULL       |   1
3    |    150     |   NULL     |   NULL       |   1
```

will represent:

```
  100
 /   \
50   150
```